# Flake8 with pep8-naming complains about camelCase imports

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I tried using the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

but `flake8` with `pep8-naming` gives the following warning:

```
N817 camelcase 'xml.etree.ElementTree' imported as acronym 'ET'
```

then I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
```

but yet again:

```
N813 camelcase 'xml.etree.ElementTree' imported as lowercase 'et'
```

**What does flake8 want here?**

Comment: You can also disable `N817` on that line with `# noqa: N817` if you don't care

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flake8 is ok with the following acronyms:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et
import xml.etree.ElementTree as eT
```

More verbose variants are also possible:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as eTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
```